# Bash Script Argument Regex Group Conflict

Tags: bash, quoting

I have a simple bash script:

```
input_dir="`dirname $1`/`basename $1`/"
output_dir="`dirname $2`/`basename $2`/"
ext=$3
...
...
...
echo -n `rename "-f" "'s/.*([0-9]{11}_[0-9]{11}).*\.(.*$)/$1.$2/'" "$output_dir"*.$ext`
```

The problem is that it does not work because the match groups `$N` conflict with command line arguments to the script. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you can stop the shell from interpreting a [metacharacter](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/help/doc/primer/node109.html)
by escaping it with a backslash (`\`).  So, you can prevent *all* the
`$` in the `rename` argument from being expanded by prepending a
backslash:

```
echo -n `rename "-f" "'s/.*([0-9]{11}_[0-9]{11}).*\.(.*\$)/\$1.\$2/'" "$output_dir"*.$ext`
```

In this particular case, since the string `s/.*([0-9]...$2/` does not
need any shell-level substitutions (the whole point of your question
is how to prevent them), you could just enclose it in single quotes
(`'`) which prevents all shell processing:

```
echo -n `rename "-f" 's/.*([0-9]{11}_[0-9]{11}).*\.(.*$)/$1.$2/' "$output_dir"*.$ext`
```

(Note that you do not need quotes around the `-f`, since it does not
contain any shell metacharacters.)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the question you asked: use single quotes around a literal string where you don't want any substitution to happen. If you need a single quote in that string, type it as `'\''`.

```
echo -n `rename "-f" 's/.*([0-9]{11}_[0-9]{11}).*\.(.*$)/$1.$2/' "$output_dir"*.$ext`
```

There's something else wrong with your code. The result of a variable susbtitution like `$1` and `$2` or a command substitution like `` `rename …` `` is parsed by the shell, it performs word splitting and globbing on the result. **Always use double quotes around variable substitutions and command substitutions** unless you know you need to omit them. Furthermore, don't use backquotes, as they handle nested quotes in tricky and shell-dependent ways. All shells outside museums support the saner `$(…)` syntax. Also you need a `--` on the invocations of `dirname` and `basename`, in case `$1` or `$2` starts with a `-` and thus looks like an option.

```
input_dir="$(dirname -- "$1")/$(basename -- "$1")/"
output_dir="$(dirname -- "$2")/$(basename -- "$2"/)"
ext="$3"    # here it would be ok to omit the quotes, but if you're unsure of the rules, put the quotes in
echo -n "$(rename -f 's/.*([0-9]{11}_[0-9]{11}).*\.(.*)$/$1.$2/' "$output_dir"*".$ext")"
```

As an aside, I don't understand what you're trying to achieve here. The way you're invoking it, `rename` doesn't produce any output.